# Trying to get the max values in decending order mySQL

Tags: sql

Hi i have a film recommender program running in Java with some SQL, I have to bring back the top 5 movie recommendations in order from the highest rating to the lowest rating every thing is grand until i bring the results back they are not in order from highest to lowest, for example number 3 is wrong, i was just wondering if its my code have a look

### 1) [See Also] A Few Good Men  [Rating] 5

### 2) [See Also] AVP: Alien vs. Predator  [Rating] 5

### 3) [See Also] The Hurt Locker  [Rating] 4

### 4) [See Also]   [Rating] 5

### 5) [See Also] Batman  [Rating] 5

```
+ "SELECT FILM,(film_total_ratings/number_of_ratings) as ratings_rating "
                    + "FROM( "
                    + "SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_ratings, FILM, "
                    + "   SUM(RATING) as film_total_ratings, "
                    + "   SUM(CASE WHEN EMAIL LIKE '%" + email
                    + "%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rated"
                    + "   FROM  ratings GROUP BY film HAVING rated=0 "
                    + "ORDER BY MAX(RATING) Desc" + ") TMP_Film LIMIT 5");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the `order by` on the outer query.  This is a general rule in SQL -- don't depend on `order by` in subqueries, except in some very limited circumstances.

That is good advice, but better advice is to order by what you really want.  So, instead of `LIMIT 5`, do:

```
ORDER BY ratings_rating DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Ordering by the right thing (in this case the calculated column in the outer query) should fix your problem.

EDIT:

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT FILM, (film_total_ratings/number_of_ratings) as ratings_rating
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_ratings, FILM,
            SUM(RATING) as film_total_ratings, "
             SUM(CASE WHEN EMAIL LIKE '%" + email + "%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rated
      FROM  ratings GROUP BY film HAVING rated=0 "
     ) TMP_Film
ORDER BY ratings_rating DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: No i still cnt get it to work could you provide a sample of what you mean please.

Comment: The only problem is its printing the lowest to the highest and DESC dosent work

Comment: @user3136938 . . . `DESC` should work.  That is what it is there for.